# Making XML requests in Angular 4.3's HttpClient

Tags: angular

How can I make XML requests with HttpClient in Angular 4.3? The options doesn't seem to accept xml as a responseType.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What results have you got?

Comment: @Fjut You can always override the `Content-Type` header but I want to see if there's anything native in the Angular APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Since HttpClient (v 4.4.) http methods (like get) as responseType option only allow  'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text', you can read XML data like this:

```
  this.http.get("your_url", { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/xml' }), responseType: 'text' })
  .subscribe(xmlData => {
    console.log(xmlData);
  });
```

visit https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient